# XFillPolygon: Transpent fill with out using a pixmap?

Tags: transparency, xlib

Because of a driver problems using XFillPolygon with StippleFill and a pixmap is extremly slow. The driver providers are also extremly slow in providing a fix so I need a workaround.

Is there a way to fill a polygon with a transparent color using XFillPolygon with out using a stiple fill and a pix map?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a great amount of research I reached the conclusion that it can not be done through xlib. However it can be done by hardware specific X extensions. So my next step from here is to get a workaround from the hardware provider.